# Disable user interaction on tabBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton, tabbar

I am displaying an image right after the app `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, the app consists in a tab bar, and in the first view i have some buttons.
The user can only continue to use the app after he press the button in that first image, the problem is, some users can interact with the tab bar, and the buttons in the first view even with the image above all.
How i can completely disable the user interaction on those buttons and in the tabBar, and enable then only when the button is pressed and the image disapear?

Comment: Dont show interface elements that the user should not use! How about presenting that first view you mention modally, hiding the tabbar entirely?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To disable:

```
UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

To enable:

```
UITabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I think tabbar should be tabBar

Comment: In Swift 3 its equivalent is : `UITabBarController.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

```
  if let items =  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items {

        for i in 0 ..< items.count {

            let itemToDisable = items[i]
            itemToDisable.isEnabled = false

        }
    }
```

Comment: this can be done in one line: `tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }`

Answer (score 0):

somehow i didn't fully understand what you described,but have you tried disabling your buttons using following code?

```
    button1.Enabled=false;
```

also you can disable images click function using

```
    image1.Enabled=false;
```

Comment: You may want to change that capital "E" to a lower case "e".

Comment: and `false` to `NO`... is this Java/C#?

Comment: Sorry guys,thought its in c#